# Scroll bar is not activating?

Tags: html, css

I were trying to add scroll bar at this part of html document,but scroll bar doesn't working properly,it is appearing without any button,but what can i do todo so that it will work properly?

```html
<div class="test-1" style="overflow-y:scroll">
  <div class="test-2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will only "work properly" if the child elements overflow the parent. There is nothing in the code you have shared that would cause the children to overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `height` on `.test-1` so when content of this div overflows its height scroll bar will work.

```html
<div class="test-1" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 70px; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="test-2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `overflow-y: auto` so now scroll bar will only appear when content overflows parents height and not before.

```html
<div class="test-1" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 70px;">
  <div class="test-2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Internet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```